# How to update a form attribute from view code in django

Tags: python, django

I have a page for updating a user profile in my django project.  The view code looks like this:

```
@login_required
def updateProfile(request, user_id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.user_id = user_id
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)

    else:
        profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user_id = self.user_id) # don't know if this will actually work.
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(profile)
        context = {
            'user' : request.user,
            'form' : profile_form
        }
        return render(request, 'myapp/profile.html', context)
```

My form looks like this:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['age', 'skill_level']
```

My user profile looks like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=18)
    skill_level = models.ForeignKey(SkillLevel)
```

When this gets posted to, we receive what appears to be a valid `user_id` along with a valid form.  In the `UserProfileForm` form we do not include `user_id` so that when it renders the user cannot decide to swap that out.  Instead, the user_id gets posted back as a separate parameter (as I type this out, I realize it's kind of weird..).  I want to save the `UserProfile` encapsulated by `UserProfileForm` to the database on post, so I give it a `user_id` and try to call `.save(commit=True)` on it, which returns `"Column 'user_id' cannot be null"`.

My question is simple, how can I get that underlying UserProfile object saved from the form data with the information at hand?

Comment: can you show me the UserProfile model and when your profile updating user is logged or not  ?

Comment: @dhana Added UserProfile model.  I don't understand the second part of the question.  The user should be logged in, yes.

Comment: yes, when you updating the userprofile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard Django form handling idiom in case like that is

```
@login_required
def updateProfile(request, user_id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)  # Get just object, but don't save yet
            obj.user = request.user        # set user (or user_id)
            obj.save()                     # Save object
            return index(request)

    else:
        profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user_id = self.user_id) # don't know if this will actually work.
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(profile)
        context = {
            'user' : request.user,
            'form' : profile_form
        }
        return render(request, 'myapp/profile.html', context)
```

Note that form data is not in fields, so `form.my_field = 123` won't work - form data is parsed to `form.cleaned_data` dictionary where `form.save()` reads it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The only problem I see with this solution is that if the user profile already exists in the database, the save will fail won't it?

Comment: You could actually do get_or_create before checking if POST and in POST branch set when creating a form, set `instance = profile`

Answer (score -1):

use the request.user for userProfile user, do this way

```
@login_required
def updateProfile(request, user_id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        form.user = request.user

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)

    else:
        profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user = request.user) # don't know if this will actually work.
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)
        context = {
            'user' : request.user,
            'form' : profile_form
        }
        return render(request, 'myapp/profile.html', context)
```